# Multiple dataset not properly working if dataset is more than 6 when remote data sources used

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using **angular-typehead#1.0.2** with **typehead#0.11.1** and **bloodhound#0.11.1**

I am using multiple datasets with Typeahead with remote data sources.

When i am typing word on  input text box then sometimes total remote calls is going but sometimes not calling properly.

Anyone encounter this issue please help on this.

See below sample example.

```js
var request1 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request1&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request2 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request2&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request3 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request3&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request4 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request4&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request5 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request5&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request6 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request6&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request7 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request7&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
var request8 = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/request.php?search_type=request8&search_text=%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
      return settings;

    },
    filter: function(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        return $.map(data.data.search_result, function(match) {
          return {
            match: match.text
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

Datasets = [{
    name: 'request1',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 1',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request1.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request2',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 2',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request2.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request3',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 3',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request3.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request4',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 4',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request4.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request5',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 5',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request5.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request6',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 6',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request6.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request7',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 7',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request7.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'request8',
    display: 'name',
    templates: {
      header: 'Search Header 8',
      suggestion: function(e) {
        return ('<div class="select-drop-down-item"><a href="#' + e.slug + '">' + e.name + '</a></div>');
      },
      footer: '<div class="dataset-footer"></div>',
      empty: ''
    },
    source: request8.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 5
  },
];
```